# Directory structure when unzipping file on the server with PHP

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I have a site I am creating when a user signs up I unzip a file that holds the current folder structure for the users profile.

The folder structure is housed in the users directory as a zip `/u/folders.zip` what I thought I was doing is creating the following structure:

```
-u
--folders.zip
--newamazingusername
---index.php
---folder1
---folder2
----subfolder1
----subfolder2
---folder3
```

What it is creating instead is this:

```
-u
--folders.zip
--newamazingusername
---folders
----index.php
----folder1
----folder2
-----subfolder1
-----subfolder2
----folder3
```

Processing file:

```
<?php
require_once( "../../assets/inc/connection.php" );

if ( !empty($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['username']) ):
    $get_username = $_GET['username'];
    $get_email = $_GET['email'];

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $hash = **[REDACTED CODE] Assume I am Hashing my password properly**
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET username='" . $get_username . "' WHERE email='" . $get_email . "'";
        // use exec() because no results are returned
        $conn->exec($sql);

        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $fileLocation = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/u/folders.zip';
        $newfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/u/' . $get_username . '.zip';

        if (!copy($fileLocation, $newfile)) {
            echo "failed to copy";
            header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '?error=foldercopyfail');
            exit();
        }
        $res = $zip->open($newfile);
        if ($res === TRUE) {
            $zip->extractTo($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/u/' . $get_username);
            $zip->close();

            header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/u/' . $get_username );
        } else {
            echo 'doh!';
        }
        unlink($newfile);

        exit();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

else :
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '?error=noaccess');
endif;


?>
```

I need to unzip the folders in the zip at the root of the user folder. I am pretty sure its an issue with the copy() if snippet.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Based on your PDO query, I'm going to assume you are incorrectly hashing your passwords as well. The PDO query should be using prepared statements, and parameterized. That is not related to the question though so the first 15 lines of your script can also be removed, also the last 11.

Comment: what is the layout of the folder in the `folders.zip` file?

Comment: User3783243 - thank you for your detailed help. I actually don't need the password anymore.

Comment: Hasta - it's a index.php 3 folders with index.php files in them and a folder with 3 empty folders in them.

Answer (score 0):

Try change this :

```
$res = $zip->open($newfile);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/u/' . $get_username);
    $zip->close();

    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/u/' . $get_username );
} else {
    echo 'doh!';
}
```

with this :

```
$res = $zip->open($newfile);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
        $fileinfo = pathinfo($filename);
        copy("zip://".$newfile."#".$filename, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/u/' . $get_username . $fileinfo['basename']);
    }
    $zip->close();

    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/u/' . $get_username );
} else {
    echo 'doh!';
}
```

Please read the [user contributed note](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php#100802) on the php docs page of `extractTo()` for the better explanation.

Comment: I figured it out. I had zipped my original folder structure up in a root directory named 'folders' once i changed the zip everything was working properly. So instead of zipping one folder containing 4 folders and a php file. I zipped the 4 folders and php file. Its always the simplest of things. thanks for your help!

Comment: I agree. Sometimes me too, misses the simplest solution ;)